# if statement not giving required output

Tags: c++, if-statement, error-handling, logic

I should enter a letter `x` and a number `y` and my code should give the letter that comes after `n` letters and the letter should be of the same case.

example:
input `y 3`
output `b`

but when I input `y 1000`, the supposed output is `k`, but it gives accented `a` and I have no idea why!

it works just fine for upper case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x;
    long long y, l;
    cin >> x >> y;
    l = y % 26;
    if ((x >= 'a') && (x <= 'z'))
    {
        x = x + l;
        if (x > 'z')
        {
            x -= 26;
        }
    }
    else if ((x >= 'A') && (x <= 'Z'))
    {

        x = x + l;
        if (x > 'Z')
        {
            x -= 26;
        }
    }
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and watch `x` closely. I suspect you're going to discover quickly that each of those `x = x + l;` statements is generating a value of `x` you're not expecting.

Comment: excuse me I am still new to all of that, why is that happening I have noticed it multiple times

Comment: Unrelated recommendation: Look into the `isupper` and `is lower` functions.

Comment: `char` on your platform, like most, is *signed*. The representable values of `char` are nearly always in the range -128...127 (though you can verify that with `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`). The integer value of ascii `'y'` is 121. Adding 12 to that (1000 mod 26)  will cause a signed overflow, which invokes UB. What is *actually* likely happening is sign wrapping (though again, not defined behavior).  The result is (presumably) a negative integer value stored in `x`, which will answer false to `x > 'z'` (because it isn't greater, in fact, it isn't even greater than zero).

Comment: Terminology note: UB -> [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Code is a description of program behaviour. When you describe an action for which there is no defined behaviour, the program becomes invalid and technically anything could happen.

Comment: @WhozCraig "Adding 12 to that (1000 mod 26) will cause a signed overflow, which invokes UB" --> not UB.  There is no signed integer overflow in OP's code.  This is an issue about assigning an out-of-`char`-range value, but that is not UB nor overflow.

Comment: I used a debugger and I found the value of x, in that case, would be -123 how to solve that?

Comment: does using an intermediate variable solve this issue?

Comment: @tasneem  As mentioned,  the proper way to determine if a letter is upper case is to use `std::isupper` and lower case it is `std::islower`.  The system knows what are lower case and upper case characters (maybe there are foreign lower/upper characters), plus testing like this `if ((x >= 'a') && (x <= 'z'))` will not work if the letters are not contiguous in the collating sequence.  It will fail miserably on an EBCDIC system.

Comment: @tasneem *and my code should give the letter that comes after n letters* -- Honestly, the code is broken, given this description.  The only way to do this correctly is to have an array of all the characters of the alphabet, and use that array -- in other words: `const char* lower="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`  and then the same thing for upper case.  Doing things like adding 1 to some value you picked off the ASCII table is not the proper way to do this assignment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It would be interesting to a complete suggested approach.  `std::isupper` and friends have trouble with negative `char` and are _locale_ sensitive.  `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is highly portably yet does not take performance advantage of common sequential-ness of A-Z (or partial sequential-ness in EBCDIC).  Could use a look-up table.  There are many ways to solve the overall goal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- Yes, I shouldn't have stated the "only way".  A lookup table would have also been a solution, as you've stated.

Answer (score 0):

OP's `x = x + l` suffers from attempting to store an out-of-`char` range value to a `char`.  This leads to implementation defined behavior and not what OP wants.

Instead, save the sum in a wider type than `char`.  After completing various tests, then assign to the `char x`.

```
    int sum = x + l;
    if (sum > 'z')
    {
        sum -= 26;
    }
    x = sum;
```

Comment: oh that makes a lot of sense thanks